# How to make tableview cell "detailLabel" editable?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextfield

I am trying to implement a suggestion offered by already answered question, but I am stuck on getting it to work, so looking for some help.

Here is the post I am trying to implement: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3067579/589310

I am trying to use the solution offered by "ridale" on how to make a "detailLabel" editable as part of a TableView.  I hope it will allow me to directly edit a cell and enter a number.  It doesn't seem too common as a UI, but "SmartRecord" does it and I want to emulate it.

Here is the only line that gives me an error:

```
UITextField *tmpView = [self detailLabel:indexPath];
```

I get this error:

Instance method `-detailLabel:` not found `(return type defaults to 'id')`

I assume it is because *my* self is different than the original poster.

I added a TableView directly to my existing controller.  It is not a TableViewController directly:

```
@interface EditViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UITableView            *tableSettings;
}
```

I can fill the table and interact with it, so I know it works (at some level anyway).

I have tried changing self to my table control or the cell directly:

`UITextField *tmpView = [tableSettings detailLabel:indexPath];`

I can't find anything that responds to the "detailLabel" method.

I am also not sure if the proposed solution is complete or uses more code not shown.

This is the only error I get, so I am hopeful once I solve it, it will work ;-)

Comment: I don't think you're referencing `self` correctly. Is that file a subclass of `UITableViewCell`? If not, you won't have access to its methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-(UITextField*)detailLabel:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath` is not present in `UITableView` or any other classes provided by Apple.

The frame position is just for sample. Modify that such that it would come in place of your detailLabel.

You have to write your own method which returns a `UITextField`, something as following

```
-(UITextField*)detailLabel:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)];
    textField.delegate = self;
    //assuming myList is array of NSString
    NSString* str = [myList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    textField.text = str;
    return [textField autorelease];
}
```